# Efficient algorithm for solving a bilinear Diophantine system

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algorithms

I wonder if there is an efficient algorithm for finding an integer solution $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, $(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ for the following type of system of equations

$$
a_{1,1} x_1 y_1 + a_{1,2} x_1 y_2 + \cdots + a_{1,n^2} x_n y_n = b_1
\\
a_{2,1} x_1 y_1 + a_{2,2} x_1 y_2 + \cdots + a_{2,n^2} x_n y_n = b_2
\\
\vdots
\\
a_{n,1} x_1 y_1 + a_{n,2} x_1 y_2 + \cdots + a_{n,n^2} x_n y_n = b_n
$$

where $a_{i,j}, b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is okay to find just one solution. Does anyone have a clue?